# Udp broadcast vs unicast: which is faster?

Tags: networking, udp

I've got a question about UDP-transfer: How does the transfer-time of a datagram differs if it is sended as Broadcast or Unicast (same Datagram-packet and network). Which conditions affect the transfer-time of broadcast-/unicast-packets ? How does the time, taken by the socket.send(packet) calls, differs?

thx

PS: Wifi is the network I'm working with

Answer (score 2):

In terms of transmitting the frame, it is dependent upon the underlying MAC layer.

With Ethernet, we use CSMA/CD, which basically transmits the frame and if collision is encountered, it stops sending and drops the frame.

With 802.11 (wireless), we use CSMA/CA. In this approach, sending unicast is more expensive (and takes more time) since it does RTS/CTS (request to send/clear to send) exchnage before it sends the unicast frame. For broadcast, 802.11 does not do any such things and hence is faster. But, then it is also more unreliable as compared to unicast frames.

Comment: So if I want to send a packet to e.g. 5 devices in the wifi-network, I have to send one broadcast-packet or 5 specific unicast-packets. Then the time the unicast-variation needs would be around 5 times the time of the broadcast-variation, right?

Comment: Roughly yes. A uincast transmission in 802.11 happens in four steps: RTS/CTS/DATA/ACK. Since RTS, CTS, and ACK are smaller packets, the total actual transmission time savings when using broadcast may not be 5 times. But, then if congestion (high traffic) happens, then stations do backoff and in that case, the time savings might be more than 5 times! So, when there is congestion, the time needed with unicast might go up in a non-linear fashion.

Comment: So why "it is also more unreliable as compared to unicast frames"?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the network and it depends on what you consider part of the 'transfer time'.  For sending on an ethernet LAN, (either wired or wireless), most of the sending stack will be the same -- the only difference will be when determining the ethernet address to use, where the broadcast might be faster (since it uses the fixed broadcast address), while the unicast may have to do an ARP lookup to find the address.  But if the address is in the ARP cache, there's likely no difference.

Next on the ethnet itself, if its wireless or bridged (shared) wired, there's no difference --  its just a packet sent to an address.  If its a switched ethernet however, the broadcast is somewhat more likely to suffer a collision (it will collide if any switch port is busy, rather than just the destination port) which may slow it down.

Finally on the receving end, with a broadcast there are mutiple receivers while for unicast there is only one.  The broadcast receivers may well be of different speeds and load levels, so they vary in how long they take to process the packet.  So if you need to wait for all of them to deal with it, it will likely be slower, but if you need only one, it may be faster.